# importance of time interval in kalman filter for position tracking

Tags: kalman-filter

I implemented a  3d linear kalman filter to track the position of object. here are the details of the KF.

my state is 3d position only and my input(control vector) is 3d velocity (vx,vy,vz). and measurement is 3d position.

dt = time interval in state update 
std_vx,std_vy,std_vz - standard deviation in control input  e.g. 2 mtrs/sec

std_cooperative_pos_x,std_cooperative_pos_y,std_cooperative_pos_z - standard deviation of measurement error e.g. around 40 mtrs each axis

A = numpy.matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]) # State transition matrix

B = numpy.matrix([[dt,0,0],[0,dt,0],[0,0,dt]]) # control input marix

H = numpy.matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])

Q = numpy.matrix([[std_vx*std_vx*dt, 0, 0],[0, std_vy*std_vy*dt, 0],[0, 0  ,std_vz*std_vz*dt]] ) # = Ex error in input , process error

R = numpy.matrix([[std_cooperative_pos_x**2,0,0],[0,std_cooperative_pos_y**2,0],[0,0,std_cooperative_pos_z**2]]) # measurement co- variance matrix

P    = numpy.matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])

here are my few questions :

1. how much the time interval that is dt value matters in the performance of filter. as i want dt such as 10 sec ,  or 20 sec .....or upto 200 secs. for dt values upto 10 sec i am able to get some improvement i my track but beyond that its not working . I am doing something wrong or its natural .
2. i implemented a linear filter is that right as to me combination of postion and velocity over time appears to be linear only .

thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

The process noise matrix 'Q' is a covariance matrix - it must contain variances rather than standard deviations.  You have:

```
Q = numpy.matrix([[std_vxstd_vxdt, 0, 0],[0, std_vystd_vydt, 0],[0, 0 ,std_vzstd_vzdt]] ) # = Ex error in input , process error
```

You want:

```
Q = numpy.matrix([[std_vxstd_vx*std_vxstd_vx * dt *dt, 0, 0], ...
```

As you can see, the process noise matrix grows with dt^2.  So the time interval is very important if it is the time between measurements.  You need only one propagation step between measurements for this filter.  There is no advantage to multiple steps (a smaller dt) unless you are approximating non-linear state propagation or there's more measurements available.

Comment: dear @keith Brodie  thanks for your time and help . I have few doubts.

Comment: dear @keith Brodie  thanks for your time and help . I have few doubts. 1. my state matrix is only [ x,y,z]pos & control input is vel [ vx,vy,vz ].  if my concept is right ( new to this filter) then error in control input will propagate as (t)  times . so  unable to understand multiplication as t*t in Q matrix . 2.  i have two types of error in control input i.e vel one is error in the vel measurements and other is its fluctuation over the period of time interval  t or dt i.e. either 10 sec or 60 sec . how to address this control input (i.e velocity)fluctuation issue, for good results.

Comment: Hi Vicky, 1) the Q matrix is the covariance of the expected state change over the time interval dt.  The elements on the diagonal have to be variances, not standard deviations.  2) If you know the change in the variance of the position noise at each measurement you should alter the R matrix to reflect it.  The change in time between measurements is can be accommodated by adjusting dt.

Comment: Dear @keith Brodie thanks ! i agree with your answer. however my concern in 2 point was that my control input ( velocity) also varies between the sampling time interval. dtor t .  e.g .  consider dt as 10 sec , at t = 0, i made  velocity input as 6mtr/sec( with some variance of 0.25 ) , my next control input will be at t = 10 . but inbetween t0 to t10 my velocity is like 7,3,4,5,5,6,2,1,5  ( which i am not telling to kalman filter). KF will think the velocity is 6mtr/sec (with variance of 0.25) all the time between t=0 &t10..Which is not true. should i bother about this or not . if yes how

Comment: Dear @keith Brodie , in your earlier reply does it mean that std_cooperative_pos_x2 in R matrix should also be variance i.e.  (std_cooperative_pos_x2 *std_cooperative_pos_x2 ) rather than standard deviation.

Comment: Yes, exactly - it's a covariance matrix as well.

Comment: thanks @Keith Brodie ! it was a great help in understanding the basics of KF. In addition would u like to comment on my second last comment of velocity fluctuation in between sampling interval.

Comment: Since you know about the velocity fluctuations - I assume you are seeing them in data.  So let's say for example you have velocity samples every second and a position update every 10 seconds.  For each velocity sample you get you'll want to update the position estimate and the covariance matrix (P = P + Q).  Then when you get the measurement, compute the gain (K = PH^T/(HPH^T + R)) and update the covariance matrix P = (I - KH^T) P.  You can do that separately for X and Y position since they are uncorrelated (the R matrix is diagonal).  You might look at **Applied Optimal Estimation** by Gelb

Comment: bridieThanks a lot! Book seems to be quite useful.